# Preheating Onida convection microwave oven

Tags: baking, microwave

I am using Onida's microwave oven. There is no option to preheat on that. Please give me some advice how should I bake things without preheating the oven.
It's a 20 litre grill microwave oven.

Comment: You're using a microwave oven?  That's very different than a traditional (gas or electric) oven.  Microwave ovens are not suited for traditional baking.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using one of Onida's "convection" microwave oven.

Here is a link that describe how to pre-heat your oven.

http://foodomania.com/setting-oven-temperature/

In summary: Select the "bake" option. Hit Enter/start once, then choose the temperature. Hit it once again, which will let you select the time. For preheating, leave it at 0:00. Hit start/enter again. When your oven beeps, it has reached the temperature. Hit Stop and bake.

Comment: Hi Max. This is a good find. But we don't want to have link-only answers, as links on the Internet tend to go dead. Please include a summary of the solution (beside the link) when you have found it elsewhere.